# django How to subtract date from django datetime.date class

Tags: django, date

I have a model:

```
class DateModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
```

and I made some object and got it:

```
date_obj = GroupDate.objects.all().last()
print(date_obj.date)
print(type(date_obj.date))
```

so that It returned this lines:

```
2018-11-21
<class 'datetime.date'>
```

Here my question,

How to get `22` days before date from date `2018-11-21`?

Like this:

```
date_obj = GroupDate.objects.all().last()
some_int = 22
result_date = get_date_from_date(date_obj.date, some_int) # It is just example that I made.
print(result_date) # >>>2018-10-30
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> date_obj = datetime(2018, 11, 21)
>>> some_int = 22
>>> result_date = date_obj - timedelta(days = some_int)
>>> result_date
datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 30, 0, 0)
```

You could also use [relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) from [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which is a more powerful library with more options, docs are linked.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
>>> date_obj = datetime(2018, 11, 21)
>>> some_int = 22
>>> result_date = date_obj - relativedelta(days =+ some_int)
>>> result_date
datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 30, 0, 0)
```